# Powershell script via GPO on Logon not working correctly

Tags: windows, powershell, script, group-policy

I made a Powershell script to remove the Windows Store and Cortana on Windows 10. I made and tested the Script successfully. Now i added the script to the LogonScripts on a GPO and tested the Script is running, also successfully. But it is not doing what is should do.

First of al, this is the Script:

```
$WSV =(Get-AppxPackage -Name "*WindowsStore*").name
if ($WSV -eq "Microsoft.WindowsStore") 
    {Get-AppxPackage -allusers "*WindowsStore*" | Remove-AppxPackage}

$Cor =(Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.549981C3F5F10).name
if ($Cor -eq "Microsoft.549981C3F5F10")
    {Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.549981C3F5F10 | Remove-AppxPackage}
```

It simply checks the existence of the AppX-Package and if it exist it will remove it. This works if the script is started by hand. But it is not working as Logon-Script. My first thought, the script is not running at all. So i added the creation of a folder in C-root, and i can confirm the script is running by the creation of this folder.

So why is the not working as desired? Is there a way get the error-message of the script somehow?

Execution-Policy is unrestricted. It is run on the Computer configuration of the GPO, so it should have Computer rights.

Comment: Try running it as a "Startup" script rather than a "Logon" script and see if that does the trick. Since Startup Scripts run as `SYSTEM` and the command is using `-allusers` parameters, I suspect that when you run as a logon script, there is a permission issue. Just run as a startup script instead and then check to confirm whether or not that resolves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it also does not work. I tried Logon, Startup and even shutdown script. But none of those works.

Comment: In your powershell script, put a line to write to a file, just so you know the script is actually running.

Comment: @LPChip i did, so i can confirm the script is running.

Comment: I am a little further. I just created a file containing the two variables and noticed they are empty. So some how the ''' $WSV =(Get-AppxPackage -Name "*WindowsStore*").name''' will give an empty value.

Comment: You can use **Event Viewer | Application and Services Logs | Windows PowerShell** to confirm that as well. The latest example of logic is what I've used successfully as startup script. If you run  `Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.WindowsStore` and it comes back null or blank, then that means that app is removed from that system. Try it on another Windows Store is installed and see if it work.

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT Well the problem is,  `Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.WindowsStore` will give the exact value while run in Powershell by hand, but it comes null when running in the script.

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT i did not downvoted your Answer, must did someone else.  I tested on 2 Computers, with the same result. One is just completely new installed.  Oh i forgot to mention, we run Windows 10 Enterprise, and I tested on 1909. I know the Cortana removal only works from 20H1.There a now errors in the event viewer. It only gives the information the script did run.

Comment: @Roman78 Feel free to comment on my answer too but run your script like this from the system `Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\path\to\test.ps1"` and tell me if this Windows shows any PowerShell level errors to troubleshoot this issue further? Meaning run is manually from cmd.exe that way elevated and tell me what happens?

Comment: Sooo.... It is working. But only for the current user. I changed the script and removed the `-allusers` flag and changed it to run as user logon script.

Answer (score 1):

Run as a Startup Script rather than a Logon Script since the command is using the `-AllUsers` parameter to ensure the permission is sufficient to remove the packages for all users when run.

I would also put the `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` in the script even though you say you have execution policy set to this already just in case.

Lastly, the removal of the package requires the full package name as far as I can tell so use the below PowerShell to get this for the app you are removing.

Use the PowerShell logic as specified in the below commands rather than what you are currently using logic wise to help resolve.

### PowerShell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted;

Get-AppxProvisionedPackage –Online | % {
    If($_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft.WindowsStore")
        {Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName $_.PackageName}
    };

Get-AppxProvisionedPackage –Online | % {
    If($_.DisplayName -eq "Microsoft.549981C3F5F10")
        {Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName $_.PackageName}
    };
    
"Microsoft.WindowsStore" | %{
    $p = (Get-AppxPackage -Name $_ | %{$_.PackageFullName});
    If($p){Remove-AppxPackage -Package $p -AllUsers};
    };

"Microsoft.549981C3F5F10" | %{
    $p = (Get-AppxPackage -Name $_ | %{$_.PackageFullName});
    If($p){Remove-AppxPackage -Package $p -AllUsers};
    };
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-AppxProvisionedPackage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/get-appxprovisionedpackage?view=win10-ps)
- [Remove-AppxPackage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage?view=win10-ps)

---

Answer (score 0):

Your PowerShell code is wrong.

```
$WSV =(Get-AppxPackage -Name "*WindowsStore*").name
# can also be written as
$WSV = Get-AppxPackage -Name "*WindowsStore*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

This query will sometimes return an array depending on the number of elements returned:

```
PS > Get-Item *.html, *.log

    Directory: /Users/megamorf

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-----          06.04.2020    18:04            730 back-to-work.html
-----          05.10.2020    12:32           4269 jmeter.log
-----          28.09.2020    14:41         246873 olv.log
-----          20.10.2020    16:28         170945 web.log

PS > $Result = (Get-Item "*.log").Name
PS > $Result.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS > $Result = (Get-Item "*.html").Name
PS > $Result.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

The comparison operator `-eq` is not correct for when you're dealing with arrays. In that case you want to use `-in` (`$obj -in $array`) or `-contains` (`$array -contains $obj`).

The entire code can be simplified as:

```
$AppsToDelete = @("Microsoft.WindowsStore", "Microsoft.549981C3F5F10")

foreach ($UnwantedApp in $AppsToDelete) {
    Get-AppxPackage -Name $UnwantedApp -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but also `$WSV = Get-AppxPackage -Name "*WindowsStore*" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` will also give an empty value.

Comment: It seems that the Get-AppxPackage's `Name` parameter does not support wildcards anymore. You can achieve the same by filtering it in the next pipeline step: `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*WindowsStore*"}`

Comment: The problem is `Get-AppxPackage` is not working on the script. I did several tests and came to that conclusion. Other commands, also those who needs adminrights, are working fine.

Comment: Just tested again. You need to provide the `-AllUsers` flag. Otherwise you get an empty result.

Comment: Aha... i'm a little bit further again. Declaring the variable works now with the `-AllUsers` flag. But the Remove still does not work. So even `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.WindowsStore | Remove-AppxPackage` does not work from the script within.